# How to get sim ICCID number on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to retrieve the SIM ICCID number in my WP8 app.
How can I do this?

Comment: what have you actually tired..? and existing code..? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1cd5e507-7fed-4c62-88b8-cc1544079357/sim-card-information-iccid-imsi-msisdn?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Right now I couldn't try anithing, I'm just garhering some info about this point for a future development. I read a lot and it dosen't seam so easy to do. I work for a mobile operator, so we need special access for this data?

Comment: sounds malicious in nature to me.. I am sure that the Mobile Operator you work for must have a way of providing you some insight..

Comment: Is not always so easy.... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very old question, but I have the answer in case some other people came here for the same issue.

Is possibile to get the phone IMEI only if you request OEM Access and libraries to Microsoft itelf. They provide OEM partner some Restricted API.
I think they only release those api to mobile operator

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in the WP 8 SDK to get this information.

Comment: What about this link a colleague just provide me? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn408437.aspx

Comment: That's for "mobile broadband devices" (i.e. 3G modems/hotspots) attached to Windows machines (laptops/desktops), not Windows *Phone*.

Comment: whit Windows Phone 8.1 there's some difference?